# Different handlers for different URLs in RxNetty without strings compare

Tags: rx-netty

I start use *RxNetty* and, at once, collided with problem: for each URL path must be different handler, but I didn't found simple and grateful decision.

In example, URL `127.0.0.1:8080/some_request` must has handler `SomeRequestHandler`, but, at the same time, URL `127.0.0.1:8080/simple_request` must has `SimpleRequestHandler`.

---

To solve my problem, I found this decisions:

1. Simple strings comparing by parsing URLs. This decision include more boilerplate code and it is uncomfortable.
2. [Paths annotation](http://blog.cask.co/2015/12/introducing-netty-http-from-cask/) This is very good decision, but it work only with default *Netty* (without *Rx*) and required unofficial library `netty-http`, so future support can be doubt.

---

So, how I can switch URLs paths for different handlers, but without boilerplate code (like as string comparing)? Maybe exists something like paths annotation, but for *RxNetty*?